psycopg2.errors.NullValueNotAllowed: FOREACH expression must not be null
I am using a Python script in QGIS. This script does the job with another database, but in my database (the same MCD), the script sends this error

psycopg2.errors.NullValueNotAllowed: FOREACH expression must not be null
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function insert_vue_cable_optique() line 67 at FOREACH over array

I checked the function and the line where i have the bug:
FOREACH _id_projet IN ARRAY (SELECT projets_actifs FROM "compl".connexion WHERE identifier = NEW.modification_identifier)
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO "compl".projet_noeud_infra(id_projet, id_noeud_infra) VALUES (_id_projet, _id_noeud_infra);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN NULL;

In the table compl.connexion, there is data, but the problem is with the insert into compl.projet_noeud_infra
Could you please help me ?
I tried to manually insert data into the table compl.projet_noeud_infra, but it doesn't work

Can you share your database design?

No the problem is in FOREACH _id_projet IN ARRAY (SELECT projets_actifs  .... The expression after ARRAY needs to be an actual array, as of now you are just returning a result set. You could try SELECT array_agg(projets_actifs) ... and see if that works. Or you could use Looping over query results and eliminate the need to build an array.
